# Set variable equal to negative number

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This should be a simple procedure but I am having trouble with it.  I have an insert command.  One of the values needs to be = to -1.  The field is defined as a small integer so it should accept both positive and negative values.

The insert statement is

```
insert into MasterData2 ([Ad],[Phase],[Page Type] , [Page], [Percent] , [Change Type],[UserName], [Timestamp], [Qty]) 
values(@Ref, @PhaseName , @PageType , @Page , @Percent ,@ChngType, @UserName, @Timestamp, -1)
```

The field [Qty] needs to be -1

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store both POSITIVE and NEGATIVE values, the smallest integer type you can use is smallint.  tinyint is meant for only POSITIVE values 0 through 255.

MSDN reference: [tinyint, smallint, int, bigint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

```
Data type | Range
======================
bigint    | -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)
int       | -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
smallint  | -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)
tinyint   | 0 to 255
```

See example:

```
create table #tmp (t tinyint, x smallint)
insert #tmp select 1,-1

-- OK

insert #tmp select -1,-1

--
Msg 220, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = -1.
The statement has been terminated.
```